# No response time metrics on New Relic for Heroku/Play2

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, newrelic

I've got a Play 2.1 app written in Scala running on Heroku.  I added the New Relic add-on, downloaded the java agent and unzipped into the app folder, updated my JAVA_OPTS, and pushed.  The server logging (i.e., Instances tab) works great, I can see memory, garbage, load, etc.  But the app monitoring doesn't work at all.  Nothing is showing up under response time, throughput, or Apdex on the Overview tab.  Is there anything obvious I should be checking for here?

The app is all REST services, no HTML, but I don't think that should have anything to do with it since there are separate tabs for App Server and Browser on the overview tab, and it *does* recognize my app server as JVM.  Just not recording any data.

Comment: Have you checked the "Installing on Play" section here? https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-installation There's also this blog post: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2012/09/03/install-new-relic-addon-for-play-2-framework-on-heroku/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATE*: New Relic has released a Play2 Java agent: http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/05/play-2/

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's currently a good way to get New Relic stats from a Play 2.x application.